# Why is this C code throwing expected error

Tags: c

I have been having problem with this c code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct dict
{
    char **inputs;
    char *outputs;
};


int main(){
 
    struct dict d;
    d.inputs = {"hello","hi"};
    d.outputs = "Hi!";
    return 0;
}
```

when i run the code it shows this

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:14:16: error: expected expression before '{' token
   14 |     d.inputs = {"hello","hi"};
      |                ^
```

why is this happening theres nothing wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1):

The data member `inputs`

```
char **inputs;
```

is a scalar object. So it may be initialized using braces with only one expression.

And moreover you may not assign a braced list to an object as you are trying to do

```
d.inputs = {"hello","hi"};
```

Instead you could write for example

```
struct dict
{
    char *inputs[2];
    char *outputs;
};


int main( void ){
 
    struct dict d = { .inputs = {"hello","hi"}, .outputs = "Hi!" };
    return 0;
}
```

Another approach is the following

```
struct dict
{
    char **inputs;
    char *outputs;
};


int main( void ){
 
    struct dict d;
    char *s[] = {"hello","hi"}; 
    d.inputs = s;
    d.outputs = "Hi!";
    return 0;
}
```

Or you could use a compound literal like

```
struct dict
{
    char **inputs;
    char *outputs;
};


int main( void ){
 
    struct dict d;
    d.inputs = ( char *[] ){"hello","hi"};
    d.outputs = "Hi!";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so how can i fix this

Comment: @nitusahay See my updated answer.

Comment: You can also write `d.inputs = (char*[]){"hello", "hi"};` in C99.